# html2canvas image got cropped when using responsive layout

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to save image of a webpage with responsive design (using bootstrap). I was trying to generate an image with fixed width so I used the option windowWidth.

Here is an example I created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpenbw

In the example I expect the gray area to be saved into an image. However if I have a big window size with a small windowWidth (or vise versa), the resulting image got cropped incorrectly. How can I get a correctly cropped image?

Comment: I was facing same issue. Setting min-width and max-width worked for me

Comment: @RK001 thanks for your help! Unfortunately I can't apply your solution because I need to keep the layout responsive across PC and mobile. I think it would be better if i let bootstrap handle the width for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason behind the cropped image is that it used the original height before any size changes. In your case your element gets taller when the width shrinks so it got cut off at the bottom.

My solution may not be exactly what you want to do but I hope it gives you some inspirations. Instead of capturing a single element, I managed to capture all of them with the correct size.

The idea is that you can create an iframe with the width you need, copy the elements into that and get the scrollHeight. This way you can get the height of your resized element and use it for your image.

I have modified your example to show how it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6185rn

Comment: It works if I am capturing the whole page. But when I apply it on a single element I am still having the wrong height. Turns out the styles were missing in the iframe. If I can copy the style as well I think I can get it to work. Thanks!